# How to parse Json Array

Tags: json

```
${
   "1":{
      "vertical_id":"1",
      "vertical_name":"Men",
      "url_key":"men",
      "meta_title":"Online Shopping For Men - Buy Mens Clothes, Footwear & Accessories At Fetise ",
      "meta_description":null,
      "meta_keywords":"mens apparel, mens clothing, mens accessories online, online mens footwear store, gadgets online for men\r\n",
      "intro_banner_path":"",
      "intro_heading":"",
      "intro_subheading":"",
      "show_products":"1",
      "featured_event_count":"8",
      "is_active":"1",
      "sort_order":"1",
      "twitter_handle":"fetise",
      "facebook_page":"fetise",
      "verticalUrl":"http:\/\/www.fetise.com\/men",
      "verticalUrlComponent":"men\/"
   },
   "2":{
      "vertical_id":"2",
      "vertical_name":"Women",
      "url_key":"women",
      "meta_title":"Online Shopping for Women - Buy Womens Clothes, Footwear & Accessories At Fetise",
      "meta_description":null,
      "meta_keywords":"online womens clothing store, womens apparels online, ladies footwear and accessories store, ladies personal care products online, womens fashion clothes\r\n",
      "intro_banner_path":"",
      "intro_heading":"",
      "intro_subheading":"",
      "show_products":"1",
      "featured_event_count":"0",
      "is_active":"1",
      "sort_order":"2",
      "twitter_handle":"FetiseWomen",
      "facebook_page":"FetiseWomen",
      "verticalUrl":"http:\/\/www.fetise.com\/women",
      "verticalUrlComponent":"women\/"
   }}
```

How can I parse this JSON in java?

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java?rq=1

Comment: Not only an obvious dupe but easy to google.  Go to http://json.org/ and look at the 100s of links for parsing JSON in practically any langauge of your choice.

Comment: It's not valid JSON since there is a `$` at the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used both [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) and [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/), and eventually settled on Jackson. It better suited a particular java project that required JSON parsing, and now just seems more flexible and/or familiar.

Using the Jackson [Tree Model](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonTreeModel), after discarding the leading `$` (invalid JSON):

```
// input is your JSON object
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

// could also use Jackson ObjectNodes:
JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readValue(input.getBytes(), JsonNode.class); 
JsonNode sub1 = rootNode.get("1");
JsonNode sub2 = rootNode.get("2");

if (sub1 != null)
{
    System.out.println("1.vertical_name: " + sub1.get("vertical_name"));
    System.out.println("1.meta_title: " + sub1.get("meta_title"));
}

if (sub2 != null)
{
    System.out.println("2.vertical_name: " + sub2.get("vertical_name"));
    System.out.println("2.meta_title: " + sub2.get("meta_title"));
}
```

Output:

```
1.vertical_name: "Men"
1.meta_title: "Online Shopping For Men - Buy Mens Clothes, Footwear & Accessories At Fetise "
2.vertical_name: "Women"
2.meta_title: "Online Shopping for Women - Buy Womens Clothes, Footwear & Accessories At Fetise"
```

Your input JSON is idiosyncratic in that it appears to be using a JSON object as a JSON array, with the outer object having fields `1, 2, ...`. So the above approach parses the JSON as generic [`JsonNode`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.3.4/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/JsonNode.html) objects, though you might just as well use Jackson to parse this into java `Maps` - see [Data Binding with Generics](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes#Data_Binding_with_Generics).

Navigating the resulting data structure assumes knowledge of the input, i.e. using `JsonNode.get("1");`, but you'll need to make the same assumptions regardless of how you represent the JSON.

You can also use [`JsonNode.iterator`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.3.4/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/JsonNode.html#iterator%28%29) to iterate over an unknown number of such "indices". This is useful if you don't know the number of `1`, `2`, etc.

Furthermore, you can make a java class that matches each sub-object, and use Jackson to create instances of that class given each sub-object. See [Full Data Binding (POJO) Example](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes#Full_Data_Binding_.28POJO.29_Example).

Comment: Thanks Brother.Actually I am New to this Json.Now i want to sore these Json value in 2 Bean classes like MEN & WOMEN>how can i do it.Please give some Hint.

Comment: IF if i get the json data from URl so it dificult for me to know JsonNode id.may be its more than 2.At that time how can get the value.

Comment: See the bit in the answer about `iterator`: this will give you a list of the top-level attributes from the JSON object, so that you don't need to do individual `get` calls over "1", "2", "3"